Flutter Firebase Dynamic Links Issue: Unable to Retrieve Link in `main()`
I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links in my Flutter application. When I click a dynamic link, the app opens perfectly, but I'm unable to retrieve the link in my main() function.
My Setup
pubspec.yaml Dependencies
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^latest_version
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^latest_version

void initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData? dynamicLink) async {
        final Uri? deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

        if (deepLink != null) {
          // Handle the deep link
          print('Received deep link: $deepLink');
          if (deepLink.path == '/add') {
            // Navigate to a specific page or perform an action
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addPage');
          }
        }
      },
      onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
        print('onLinkError');
        print(e.message);
      },
    );

    final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    if (initialLink != null) {
      final Uri? deepLink = initialLink.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {
        // Handle the deep link
        print('Received initial link: $deepLink');
        if (deepLink.path == '/add') {
          // Navigate to a specific page or perform an action
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addPage');
        }
      }
    }
  }



Verified that the dynamic link domain is correctly set in the Firebase console.
Ensured the dependencies in pubspec.yaml are up-to-date.
Checked the configuration in Info.plist for iOS.
Printed logs in the initDynamicLinks function to debug.


what is your main() func bro? Besides, you shouldn't use Firebase dynamic links, becuz it'll dead since 25/8/2025. https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links
